# How to get notification in view controller when bringSubviewToFront is called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My application needs a notification in the view controller when I call `bringSubviewToFront()`. I tried `viewDidAppear` but it doesn't work (Obviously I shouldn't work because view is already in the stack). I have gone through the documentation of view & viewController but didn't find anything that can solve my problem. Is there any way to get view controller notified?

Comment: Are you calling bringSubviewToFront from the ViewController? if so you  dont need a notification and can just call a method or so.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the `viewDidAppear` notification with `bringSubviewToFront`. It gets fired when you add the view as a subview or change the `hidden` property on the view. You must also make sure that your ViewController has been added as a child view controller to it's parent using 
`addChildViewController`.